# How to map form data in Symfony to an object only when form is valid?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

Imagine example form in Symfony:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
            'constraints' => 
                new NotBlank(),
                new IsUnique(),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
            'constraints' => 
                new NotBlank(),
                new IsStrongEnough(),
            ],
        ])
}
```

Now when I submit the form and make sure it's valid, I'd like the `$form->getData()` to return my DTO called `CreateAccountCommand`:

```
final class CreateAccountCommand
{
    private $email;
    private $password;

    public function __construct(string $email, string $password)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Example controller:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create(CreateAccountForm::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $this->commandBus->dispatch($form->getData());

    return new JsonResponse([]);
}
```

I cannot use this class directly using the `data_class`, because the form obviously expects the model to have setters that allow null values. The form itself works perfectly well, so is the validation.

I tried using the [Data mapper](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_data_mapper.html) method, but the `mapFormsToData` method is invoked, before the validation.

Is this possible at all? Or am I supposed to get the data as array and create the object outside the form?

Comment: in the model, some fields (email in example) can be null, but you want them being mandatory in form?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: `->add('email', EmailType::class, array('required' => true))`

Comment: The `required => true` is just a html5 validation (and it's a default anyway), not sure why you wrote that. Like I said in the question, the validation part works fine.

Comment: That way, you can override models nullable fields to validate the form. I had to use that trick the opposite way, there was non nullable properties in my model and I had to use `'required' => false` to force the validation

Comment: I don't have any problem with the validation. The question is how to return an instance of `CreateAccountCommand` with the `getData()` of the form. If you have a working solution please post it as an answer.

Comment: Yep, I'll post the way I manage forms with Symfony 4

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm used to handle form with Symfony 4.1

Let's assume you want a simple add form

The Form

```
class CreateAccountForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
    {
        //same method than yours
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'App\Entity\CreateAccountCommand'));
    }
}
```

The controller

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $createAccountCommand = new CreateAccountCommand();

    //The object is "injected" to the form, that way, it's mapped when submitted
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(CreateAccountForm::class, $createAccountCommand);

    //Form was submitted
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid())
    {
        //no need to getData(), the object $createAccountCommand is directly mapped to the form and can be used as is
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //persist, convert to json, or whatever
        $em->persist($createAccountCommand);
        $em->flush();

        return ($this->redirectToRoute('someRoute'));
    }

    //form not submitted, or has been submit with errors (isValid() == false)
    return ($this->render('account/add.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it is way too complex for what you want to do.  You'll need to use Datamapper for this.

I know this is not the best solution, but thesimplest solution would be (in my opinion) adding setters to your model class and allow null values (SOLUTION1). Another solution would be using another object for the form, and build your command after submission ( and you don't need to modify your Command - SOLUTION2).

```
public function handleForm(Request $request)
{
    /// SOLUTION 1
    $form = $this->createForm(RegisterFormType::class, new CreateAccountCommand());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $command = $form->getData();
        // do whatever you want
    }
    // ... 

    // SOLUTION 2
    $obj = new \stdClass();
    $obj->login = '';
    $obj->password = '';
    $form = $this->createForm(LoginFormType::class, $obj);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $command = new CreateAccountCommand($data->login, $data->password);
        // do whatever you want
    }
}
```

With this model:

```
final class CreateAccountCommand
{
    //// ... 
    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail(string $email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword(string $password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but maybe this answer would help someone in the same situation.

In my point of view, the `Command` (CQ(R)S meaning) is a simple DTO which accept invalid data. Therefore, you should apply contraints on it directly and not to the form.

In your exemple :

```php
final class CreateAccountCommand
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Assert\NotBlank]
        #[Assert\IsUnique]
        public string $email = '',

        #[Assert\NotBlank]
        #[Assert\IsStrongEnough]
        public string $password = '',
    ) {
    }
}
```

This way, you can benefit of all the Symfony goodies, and in your command handler force your domain models to be valid after the validation passed.